# View not updating as expected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following setup in my controller which I would expect to update my view appropriately, but it does not until I refresh the page:

```
var vm = this;
var loadingGames = $q.defer();

var getGames = function() {
  playersService.getGames({
    playerId: playerId
  }).$promise.then(function(data) {
    vm.games = data;
    loadingGames.resolve();
  });
};

var init = function() {
  getGames();
}

init();

var updateSchedule = function() {
  getGames();
  loadingGames.promise.then(function() {
    populateOptions(vm.games);
    vm.tableParams.reload();
  });
};

vm.performAction = function(action, gameId, gameType) {
  utilitiesService.performOperation(action, gameId, gameType).then(
    function() {
      updateSchedule();
    },
    function(httpError) {
      alert('Couldn\'t '+ action +' game: ' + httpError);
    });
};

var populateOptions = function(games) {
  angular.forEach(games, function(game) {
    game.options = getOptions(game);
  });
};
```

When I click the `performAction` button in my UI I expect to see updated `vm.games` in my view. However, I always need to refresh the page to see the changes. I know this is most likely related to `$scope.$apply` but I'm not grasping it at the moment.

Comment: Are you sure that `populateOptions` and `vm.tableParams.reload()` are synchronous?

Comment: How do you bind games in your view? When you set vm to this, is this refer to controller?

Comment: @Franck, yes `this` refers to the controller. I use `controllerAs` syntax.

Comment: Does `getOptions` return a promise? Is it an angular promise?

Comment: So your view bind to games not vm.games, right?

Comment: View binds to vm.games

Comment: GetOptions does not return a promise.

Comment: @MattDionis - You said `getOptions` is async, so it would have to either return a promise or take a callback. Could you please include the `getOptions` function in your question.

Comment: Sorry, getOptions is NOT async after all. It calls a service, but that service just contains a helper function. No API calls.

Comment: you call vm.tableParams.reload() but we dont see an object tableParams assigned to the ctrl in your code. Is that ok ? Dont you have an error in your console?

Comment: This is not the complete controller code. Only the relevant pieces. The controller and view function nicely other than the view not updating as soon as an action is performed.

Comment: From the chunk of code you showed i do not see anything wrong. Without the view and the rest of the code, its hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks for trying, nothing jumps out at me either. Just a note, the data I expect to update in the view is in an ng-repeat. `ng-repeat="game in $data"`

Comment: One error is your loadingGames variable.  You instantiate it only once and try to resolve it many times.  Instead,  simply return the promise from your playerService. You can chain promise,  meaning that by letting the actual then and returning the promise from your service,  the vm.games = data will be executed before the code in the next then. In your other functions, you will call getGames.then(...)

Comment: @AnthonyGarant, thank you! I think that will solve it for me. When `loadingGames` is resolved by `init()` it remains resolved. So my `updateSchedule` function does NOT actually wait for `getGames()` to resolve because it once again references `loadingGames`. Is this correct?

Comment: You got it!  I posted an answer combining both comments for future references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is your loadingGames variable.  You instantiate it only once and try to resolve it many times. When you call it first from your init function,  you resolve it.  As a result,  all the subsequent calls to getGames which are relaying on loadingGames do NOT wait because the promise is already resolved. They are therefore using the old vm.games.

To solve this problem,  simply return the promise from your playerService. You can chain promise,  meaning that by letting the actual then and returning the promise from your service,  the vm.games = data will be executed before the code in the next then. Therefore, you will call getGames.then(...) from your other functions.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm running into a `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` error when using this structure: `var updateSchedule = function() {
    getGames().then(function() {
      populateOptions(vm.games);
      vm.tableParams.reload();
    });
  };`

Comment: You need to be returning a promise from your getGames. So return PlayerService.getGames({playerId:playerId}).$promise